# Testing Django and model methods

Tags: django, testing

I wondering what is the best practice to write code for good testing. E.g.

```
class Visits(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    visited_at = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{}-{}".format(self.user, self.visited_at)
```

And I need a function wich get me only visits for current user from last day. What should I do? Make view for this and test it? Or make model methods? What is the best to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you could use a model manager for this. Should look something similar to the following.

(This isn't tested, you may have to mess with the querysets):

**managers.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Visited(models.Manager):

    def on_day(self, user, date):
        qs = self.model.objects.filter(user=user, visited_at=date)
        return qs
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from .managers import Visited

class Visits(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    visited_at = models.DateTimeField()
    objects = models.Manager()    
    visited = Visited()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{}-{}".format(self.user, self.visited_at)
```

Simply feed it the `user` and `date` information it needs to return the desired `User` set.

---

As for testing, hopefully someone can write something proper in Documentation, because there is alot I'd like to learn about it, but this is generally how I like to go about it:

**tests.py**

```
import datetime
from django.test import TestCase

class TestData(TestCase):
    yesterday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):

        cls.User1 = User.objects.create(
            name="Anon1"
        )
        cls.User2 = User.objects.create(
            name="Anon2"
        )

        cls.Visit1 = Visits.objects.create(
            user=cls.user1,
            visited_at=self.yesterday,
        )
        cls.Visit2 = Visits.objects.create(
            user=cls.user2,
            visited_at=datetime.date(2016,7,28),
        )
        cls.Visit3 = Visits.objects.create(
            user=cls.user2,
            visited_at=datetime.date(2016,8,1),
        )

class SalesRecordTest(TestData):

    def test_varieties_sold(self):
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(Visits.visited.on_day(self.yesterday, self.user), ["<User: Anon1>"])
        self.assertNotIn("Anon2", str(Visits.visited.on_day(self.yesterday, self.user)))
```

Flag your tests with `--keepdb` to keep them speedy. I haven't found any disadvantage to just using `--keepdb` every time, as it seems to update the database whenever it needs to.

Hopefully this is enough to get you started. Good luck and happy testing!